# Is there a way to make user follow links in a webview Android app?

Tags: java, android, google-chrome, android-webview, chrome-custom-tabs

I have an Android app that I created with `webview`. It works just perfect but I have a tiny problem.

The web app that I implemented to `webview` has a Google drive button that opens the Google authentication page in a new tab when clicked on web browsers on PC but when I click it in the mobile app it's not working.

I just want it to redirect to a mobile browser which user prefer (chrome, opera etc). Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Use [Chrome Custom Tabs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/android/custom-tabs/overview/)

```
String url = ¨https://paul.kinlan.me/¨;
CustomTabsIntent.Builder builder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();
CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = builder.build();
customTabsIntent.launchUrl(this, Uri.parse(url));
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but the problem is the url is in a button in the website that embedded in webview so i can't be able to create another button holds the url.

Comment: @erkutr I think you should use ```fragment``` make own a layout to shows chrome custom tab, then pass the data from ```onClick``` method.